# TCP_FASTOPEN undeclared

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm coding a small server that uses [TCP Fast Open](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7413) option through `setsockopt()`. However I am getting this error from gcc :

```
$gcc server.c
server.c: In function 'main':
server.c:35:34: error: 'TCP_FASTOPEN' undeclared (first use in this function)
    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN, &qlen, sizeof(qlen) == -1)
```

Here is the server's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    short port = 45000;
    int max_conn = 10;
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in ssi;
    ssi.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ssi.sin_port = htons(port);
    ssi.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&ssi, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't bind socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    // TFO
    int qlen = 5;
    if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_FASTOPEN, &qlen, sizeof(qlen)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Couldn't set TCP_FASTOPEN option: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(fd, max_conn) != 0)
    {
        printf("Could'nt listen on socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in csi;
    int clen = sizeof(csi);

    int cfd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&csi, &clen);

    return 0;
}
```

Why does gcc gives this error?

The macro `TCP_FASTOPEN` is located in `include/uapi/linux/tcp.h` in the kernel and its value is 23 so I tried to redefine it in my code, then it does compile and run but the option is not sent by the server as an answer to a TFO request (in the SYN-ACK).

Does anybody knows why? Is this related to the compilation issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen` [needs to be set to 2](https://lwn.net/Articles/508865/) to enable server-side use of TCP fast open option:

> The tcp_fastopen file can be used to view or set a value that enables the operation of different parts of the TFO functionality. Setting bit 0 (i.e., the value 1) in this value enables client TFO functionality, so that applications can request TFO cookies. Setting bit 1 (i.e., the value 2) enables server TFO functionality, so that server TCPs can generate TFO cookies in response to requests from clients. (Thus, the value 3 would enable both client and server TFO functionality on the host.)

Also, TCP_FASTOPEN macro needs to be included with `#include <netinet/tcp.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your glibc doesn't have support for TCP_FASTOPEN - even if your keernel has (since it's not available when you include standard socket headers). So you can't really use it using glibc glue code (of which `setsockopt()` is part of).

Comment: It [apparently](http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/lt-netinet-tcp-h-gt-sync-with-Linux-td218372.html) have been added in glibc 2.17 and I have 2.19 so I am a bit confused here. If I add `#include <netinet/tcp.h>`, macro is defined but there is still no TFO SYN-ACK option sent.